# How do the European ATC strikes affect us as pilots?

Tags: air-traffic-control, eu

So every once in awhile I see an article talking about the air traffic control strikes in Europe like this one:  [European air traffic controllers to strike](http://english.cntv.cn/20140124/102596.shtml).

How does this affect me if I am flying to Europe?  Do they just close the doors and all airspace becomes uncontrolled airspace?  I'm guessing not, but that's what I envision when I hear that!  What happens if they go on strike while I'm over the ocean on my way there?

Comment: There are a couple of NOTAMs on page 2 & 3 here that might help someone formulate an answer: http://www.pprune.org/rumours-news/523784-europe-wide-atc-strike-10-october.html

Answer (score 1):

Since these strikes are announced in advance, you will not be caught by surprise half way accross the ocean. If you try to file a flightplan through the soon to be closed airspace, the [CFMU](https://www.public.cfmu.eurocontrol.int/PUBPORTAL/gateway/spec/index.html) will not accept your plan. There will be no IFR traffic in the airspace before they close down the service.

I don't know about VFR.